# How to stop the GET method is not supported for this route from showing?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have a working Laravel project with loads of different routes.

I'm currently testing it and one of my tests was to check if a user were to use a delete or post route from the URL. I didn't know what the application would do honestly and it outputted the typical:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE

which I have seen a million times. Is there a way to stop this error from coming up and instead output an error screen or simply redirect to a different view?

Answer (score 1):

The error message:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE.

should only appear when your Laravel site has `APP_DEBUG` set to `true` (in the `.env` file).

When `APP_DEBUG` is set to `false` as it should **always** be in on a live site, then the user will be shown a 404 error page instead.

---

You can easily test this by adding the following code to your routes file:

```php
Route::delete('test', function() {
    return 'You should never see this text when viewing url via a GET request';
});
```

Answer (score -1):

May be u didn't noticed but ur form tag method attribute and route definition is different